# Laravel Eloquent count many to many relations

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent

While having a users, companies and company_user pivot table: How to get companies sorted by their users count?

The following query is almost it. Only problem here is I just get companies who at least have one user. Every company without a user relation isn´t taken into account.

```
$companies = Company::->with('users')
    ->join('company_user', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_user.company_id')
    ->selectRaw('companies.*, count(*) as `aggregate`')
    ->groupBy('companies.id')
    ->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Example output should be:

```
company_1 (users: 4)
company_2 (users: 2)
company_3 (users: 0)
company_4 (users: 0)
```

Output with above query is:

```
company_1 (users: 4)
company_2 (users: 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of your companies are being removed by the `INNER JOIN`.  If so, you can try using a `LEFT JOIN` along with `SUM` (to count cardinality of the rows) to retain the missing data:

```
$companies = Company::->with('users')
    ->leftJoin('company_user', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_user.company_id')
    ->selectRaw('companies.*,
                 sum(case when company_user.company_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as `aggregate`')
    ->groupBy('companies.id')
    ->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I initially was also trying to use `COUNT()` as you were, but it seemed to always insist on counting `NULL` rows as 1.  Instead, I switched to `SUM()` with a `CASE` expression and it worked fine.

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Getting closer. Now I´ve got ```company_1 (users: 4); company_3 (users: 0); company_4 (users: 0); company_2 (users: 2)```

Comment: @Kristo But isn't this your desired output?

Comment: company_2 with two users isn´t in order... it´s behind companies without users